# Convert an OracleRefCursor to a List of custom C# Objects

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a Dapper statement that returns an OracleRefCursor:

```
try
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = Connection)
    {
        var parameters = new OracleDynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("refCursorReturn", null, OracleMappingType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
        IEnumerable<OracleRefCursor> temp = connection.Query<OracleRefCursor>("MySchema.MyStoredProc", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        //I need to convert the OracleRefCursor to an IEnumerable or List of MyObject

        return IEnumerable<MyObject>;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```

I can't find any documentation online about how to convert an OracleRefCursor to anything I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is (if ok with NOT using strong type like OracleRefCursor), then can use:

```
 IEnumerable<dynamic> temp = null;

 temp = connection.Query<dynamic>("MySchema.MyStoredProc", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

foreach (var dataRow in temp)
{
     var fields = dataRow as IDictionary<string, object>;
     // do something with fields. (store in datatable, list etc).
}
```